# Hardware keyboard symbol [popup] problems

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard, special-chars

I am running CM10.1 (Andromadus flavor, based on Android 4.2) on a HTC Desire Z with built-in hardware keyboard. To input keys that are not present on the keyboard, there is a symbol key that pops up a dialog where the symbol can be selected. With CM10 this symbol set was somewhat complete, but with CM10.1 some of the essential symbols such as "<" and ">" are no longer available.

So my questions are these:

- <strike>Is there any way to fix this behavior to give me the complete set of symbols even in CM10.1?</strike> (see answer below)
- <strike>Where in the source tree is the code for this popup located? What component? I would be happy to hack it in order myself as long as I can find the relevant needles in the haystack.</strike>
- <strike>Is there any app that can be used in place of the symbol popup? I am not talking about a complete soft keyboard, but rather a quick popup dialog where a symbol can be selected and inserted at the cursor position.</strike>
- How would I go about modifying my keymap to for example add "<" to Fn+comma? Shifted it's a semicolon, but Fn+comma is still the regular comma.

**Edit:** Found the solution to the first question. The symbols aren't missing, the popup has just been split. If you have a Desire Z and are unable to find the "<" or ">" characters, hold the hardware key for "(" (press FN, then hold "G") and a popup will present "[", "{", "<". So, I have updated my question to if it's possible (and how) to modify the keymap to add characters to shifted keys on the hardware keyboard.